# Black screen after nvidia driver install every time!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I've installed xUbuntu and Ubuntu 16.04 twice each because every time I try to install the Nvidia Proprietary Drivers through "Additional Drivers" I get a black screen when I restart the PC. Now I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 with the lastest Nvidia Beta Drivers and it won't boot. I can choose Ubuntu with Grub, I get a purple background and poof black screen, monitor says no signal.

I have an Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070 and a last gen intel i5 processor.

Thank you for reading this/helping me.